# Dynamic Hash-like data-structure in Fortran

Tags: data-structures, fortran

Is there a library usable in Fortran, which allows the usage of sparse dynamic arrays (hash/dictionary like) besides the [Judy arrays](http://judy.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't seen one built-in, but google returns a few:

FLibs: http://flibs.sourceforge.net/

Hash Tables: http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/evahash.html and http://www.cris.com/~Ttwang/tech/inthash.htm.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had FLib on the radar, but somehow the dictionary provided by it, slipped my attention. Otherwise my searches mostly ended up with some C++ stuff, which I do not really want to depend on...

Comment: @Haraldkl: Hope a standardized one can come in future.

Comment: I also found a red-black tree implementation over at https://www.myroms.org/blog/ and some trie implementation at https://github.com/ned14/nedtries, however they all need some more work to use them in Fortran an in my scenario especially. Thus I think there is no simply usable generic library.

Answer (score 6):

I have created an abstracted dictionary in fortran which might suit your needs.

See: https://github.com/zerothi/fdict

Basically it lets you do

```
type(dict) :: dic, dic2
dic = ('KEY'.kv.1)
dic = dic //('next'.kv. (/3.,5.,6./))
dic = dic //('string'.kv.'Hello world')
dic2 = ('string2'.kv.'Test')
dic = dic // ('dic2'.kvp.dic2)
```

Where you can save all intrinsic types and it can easily be extended to contain other data-types, it defaults to initially contain itself as another value. (the last line retains a dictionary as a pointer)

It does `.kv. == key : value` designation which is a deep copy, and
`.kvp. == key : pointer` which is a reference copy.
In this way you can store huge data without having to duplicate data and retrieve the pointer at some later point.

To elaborate on the idea, all data is stored as address pointers using a `transfer` call from a derived type containing the data pointer. In this way you trick the compiler to hand you the address of the fortran derived type, but forces you to retrieve it in the exact same manner.
By `.kv.` a pointer of the data-type is allocated and subsequently pointed to by the data-container, then afterwards the allocated pointer is `nullify`ied and *lost* thus forcing the user to know what they are doing (there is no garbage-collector in it ;) ).
By `.kvp.` the pointer is directly saved without duplicating any memory.

The nice thing is that it is fortran90 compliant.

Comment: This is almost a link only answer. Could you write something about what the library can and cannot do? What is it for? Which Fortran version it requires?

Comment: I did something similar for my own purpose using unlimited polymorphism. Does this use parametric polymorphism? Does it depend on `transfer()`?

Comment: What about now? I think explaining a larger part of the API is meaningless? No?

Comment: Yeah it is enough, do not write a manual here. Just if you want to share what technique it is based on. I saw you have a character array to save the value. Do you fill it using transfer?

Comment: Yes, I transfer the data-pointer to get the location of the stored data, so it is basically a pointer address in the character intrinsic.