# assign value to key in hash code in Fortran

Tags: hash, fortran, hashcode

I am trying to implement a hash table in my Fortran code and I have found an example on the Internet, but I can't figure out how the value is assigned to the key.

The following link redirects to the Fortran module I want to implement with a example on how to use the code.

http://didgeridoo.une.edu.au/womwiki/doku.php?id=fortran:fortran

Could anyone explain me how to assign a value to the key's in this example program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example program](http://didgeridoo.une.edu.au/womwiki/doku.php?id=fortran:hashfront) on that page shows how to use it:

```
 call hash_it(idorig, 1, idnew, ipos, .false.)

! call hash_it(idorig, ivar, idnew, ipos, noadd)
!    idorig = ID to be recoded
!    ivar   = list no. (1, 2, ..., mlists)
!    idnew  = new ID
!    ipos   = position in hash table (rarely used)
!    noadd  = option: .false. adds new IDs
!                     .true.  does not add new IDs, just looks up position
```

`idorig` is the (integer) value to be stored, and `idnew` is the (integer) key. You can then lookup `idnew` in `hlist`.

This implementation can only store integers, and uses the hash of the value as the key, i.e. you can't specify the key yourself. If this doesn't suit your needs, you may also want to look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7157998/2043465), or on the [Fortran wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Hash+tables).

Comment: Ah, Yep you are right, I was already afraid of that.  I will have to swap to a different code in that case.